# udev for /sys file not working

Tags: linux, udev, sysfs

I'm trying to set group attribute for

```
root@luna:~# ls -l /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Sep 24 08:28 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

I've created a rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-local.rules:

```
root@luna:/etc/udev/rules.d# cat 99-local.rules 
KERNEL=="intel_backlight", SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", GROUP="neil", mode="0664"
```

Whether I systemctl restart udev, udevadm control -R, or reboot the rule is not applied. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Udev creates device file entries under `/dev`. Udev rules affect those entries. Files under `/sys` are direct kernel interfaces, created by the kernel, and not affected by udev.

If you want to change ownership or permissions on a file under `/sys`, do it explicitly.

```
#!/bin/sh
chown neil /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
chmod 664 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

If the display device fires a udev event then you can run this script with a `RUN=…` action. Alternatively, run this script somewhere in the boot process, e.g. in `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this question.  The proper way to change the permission & ownership of files under /sys is by using tmpfiles configs.  For example, placing the following in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/screen-backlight.conf` would achieve what you want:

```
m /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 0664 root some_group_that_neil_belongs_to - -
```

See `man 5 tmpfiles.d` for all the options.

Comment: There's no such modifier as "m", I think you meant "z" (or "Z" for recursive).

Comment: I never used tmpfiles but I'm upvoting since the man page explicitly says that it is used to /sys: "...It is mostly commonly used for volatile and temporary files and directories (such as those located under /run/, /tmp/, /var/tmp/, the API file systems such as /sys/ or /proc/, as well as some other directories below /var/)."